# Latitude and Longitude standalone gui

Tags: user-interface, latitude-longitude

i've searched on the web and here for a similar question but unfortunately didn't found the right answer.

I would like to make a gui in python, or in C#, for retrieve the latitude and longitude over the entire earth just with a click, just like i do now but via the link:

http://www.itouchmap.com/latlong.html

How can I sort out this?

Comment: Are you creating a website, or an application?

Comment: An application, i have a script in python that uses this data as an input, i want just to automatize the process instead of going every time at the link for clicking and copy/paste the coordinates. Thanks!

Comment: Rather confused by your requirements I'm afraid. Do you want to create an application that will click a location on the map on that web page?

Comment: I want a gui like in the website above, where i click and the latitude/longitude is sent directly to my script input. The script is in python so i would like to make a python gui (TKinter?) that visualize the map of the world and let me click a location anywhere giving me the two numbers lat long. Thanks